# document.createElement("<li>") not working in IE10?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, createelement

In my below, it works fine upto IE9, but not in IE10+:

```
function createList() {

  try {

    var listObj = document.getElementById('dialedList');
    //document.getElementById('dialedDiv').style.display = "inline";
    var list = opener.dialedNumbers; // This is array
    //alert("list : "+list);
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {

      //alert(list[i])
      if (list[i] != undefined && list[i] != null && list[i] != "") {
        alert("come");
        var li = document.createElement("<li>");
        alert("not come");
        li.innerHTML = list[i];
        li.onclick = function () {
          //alert(this);
          document.getElementById('screen').value = this.innerHTML;
          document.getElementById('screen').focus();
        };
        li.onmouseover = function () {

          this.style.backgroundColor = "#719FE5";
          this.focus();
        };
        li.onmouseout = function () {

          this.style.backgroundColor = "white";
          this.focus();
        };
        listObj.appendChild(li);
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    alert(e.description);
    alert(e.message);
  }
}
```

Comment: This issue would be resolved if you used a cross-browser compatible library such as jQuery, rather than using JS only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`createElement`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-2141741547) doesn't accept HTML, it accepts an element name ("tag name"). So you don't include the angle brackets:

```
var li = document.createElement("li");
```

If you've had other browsers accepting the previous version, they were just being tolerant.

Comment: Thanks. +1 for you . I worked for the past hours.But couldn't find that.Great.

Comment: @HumanBeing if this answer solved your problem you should set the answer as accepted...

Comment: @dome: He/she can't within the first 15 minutes, probably will once enough time has passed.

Comment: @dome  T.J. Crowder is correct. I can't accept the answer for the past 15 mins.